# Akka Streams File Handling and Termination

Tags: scala, akka-stream

I have the following snippet that reads a CSV file and just prints something to the console:

```
def readUsingAkkaStreams = {

    import java.io.File
    import akka.stream.scaladsl._
    import akka.actor.ActorSystem
    import akka.stream.ActorMaterializer
    import java.security.MessageDigest


    implicit val system = ActorSystem("Sys")
    implicit val materializer = ActorMaterializer()

    val file = new File("/path/to/csv/file.csv")

    val fileSource = FileIO.fromFile(file, 65536)

    val flow = fileSource.map(chunk => chunk.utf8String)

    flow.to(Sink.foreach(println(_))).run
  }
```

I now have some questions around this:

1. The chunksize is the size in bytes. How is it handled internally? I mean would I end up in a situation that a chunk may contain only partial elements in a line?
2. How does this stream termintate? Right now it does not! I want it to know that it has read the file completely and should trigger a stop signal! Is there a mechanism to do this?

**EDIT 1:** After suggestions from the post below, I get an error message as shown in the screenshot!

[image]

**EDIT 2:**

Managed to get rid of the error by setting the maximumFrameLength to match the size of the maximum chunk size which is 65536.

```
val file = new File("/path/to/csf/file.csv")
val chunkSize = 65536
val fileSource = FileIO.fromFile(file, chunkSize).via(Framing.delimiter(
  ByteString("\n"),
  maximumFrameLength = chunkSize,
  allowTruncation = true))
```

Comment: Use the CsvParser support in Alpakka: https://developer.lightbend.com/docs/alpakka/current/data-transformations/csv.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1.As per the [docs](https://doc.akka.io/japi/akka/current/akka/stream/scaladsl/FileIO.html#fromPath-java.nio.file.Path-int-long-):

Emitted elements are chunkSize sized ByteString elements, except the final element, which will be up to chunkSize in size.

The `FileIO` source treats new lines as any other character. So yes, you will be potentially seeing the first part of a CSV line in a chunk, and the second part in another chunk. If this is not what you want, you can restructure how your `ByteString` flow is chunked by using `Framing.delimiter` (see the [docs](https://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/current/stream/stream-io.html?language=scala#working-with-streaming-io) for more info).

As a side note, `FileIO.fromFile` has been deprecated, better use `FileIO.fromPath`.

An example would be:

```
val fileSource = FileIO.fromPath(...)
  .via(Framing.delimiter(
    ByteString("\n"),
    maximumFrameLength = 256,
    allowTruncation = true))
```

2.the sink materializes to a `Future` you can map onto to do something when the stream terminates:

```
val result: Future[IOResult] = flow.runWith(Sink.foreach(println(_)))

result.onComplete(...)
```

Comment: The stream does not terminate. Additionally, your solution implies that there is a line break, but what if the line breaks are at arbitraty places? Have a look at my edited question.

Comment: I modified the maximumFrameLength to match the size of the maximum chunk size which is 65536. That obviously got rid of the error, but not sure if this is correct.

Comment: So to terminate the stream, in my example above, I had to do a System.exit(0) and this is not something what I want

Comment: Alternatively, I could terminate the stream using the ActorSystem Terminate, but this is also something that I do not want to do!